# Writing a REST API for Complex Nested Data

Tags: node.js, rest, express

So, I'm building an application in Angular which would leverage a REST API at the back, running on Node. I'm having some trouble handling the data complexity while designing this API and could use some help.

Here are the different resources, in question.

1. Doctors (each doctor may have multiple patients)
2. Patients (each patient may have multiple doctors)
3. Appointments (appointments exist for doctors, naturally)
4. Reminders (reminders may be sent from doctors to patients, not the other way around)

Now, here are some of the operations that the application may carry out, so the requirements from the API are clear.

1. Each doctor must be able to request for all his patients or a particular one.
2. Each patient must be able to request for all his doctors or a particular one.
3. Each doctor must be able to request for all his appointments (to see all patients) for a particular date, or for all days, if necessary.
4. Each patient must be able to request for all his appointments (to see all doctors) for a particular date, or for all days, if necessary.
5. Each doctor must be able to request for all appointments from a single patient.
6. Each patient must be able to request for all his appointments from a single doctor.
7. Each doctor must be able to request for all his reminders to a particular patient.

Remember, the request could naturally be a POST, GET, DELETE or PUT. Now, here is where I am so far. I'm only mentioning the URL, the operation on each when sent a POST, GET, DELETE or PUT is self-explanatory.

1. `/doctors/`
2. `/doctors/:id`
3. `/doctors/:id/patients` (returns a list of `/patient/:id`)
4. `/doctors/:id/appointments`
5. `/patients/`
6. `/patients/:id`
7. `/patients/:id/doctors` (returns a list of `/doctors/:id`)
8. `/patients/:id/appointments`

Now, I'm okay with the ones above. Here are my questions.

1. How do I design a URL for task number 7 without having nesting like `/doctors/:id/patients/:id/appointments`?
2. Also, I can get all appointments for a doctor or for a patient quite easily with the above. What about particular appointments? `/doctors/:id/appointments/:id` or `/patients/:id/appointments/:id` doesn't feel quite right.
3. Also, what about appointments to see a particular patient or a particular doctor?
4. And what about appointments for each doctor or patient on a particular date?

I feel like too much nesting is going on. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list of endpoints looks good. I guess there can be different opinions about what you asked.

The following are my opinions about what could be done:

> How do I design a URL for task number 7 without having nesting like `/doctors/:id/patients/:id/appointments`?

I would suppose a collection of reminders would exist and define it as follows:

```
/doctors/:doctorid/reminders
/doctors/:doctorid/reminders/:patientid
```

> Also, I can get all appointments for a doctor or for a patient quite easily with the above. What about particular appointments?
>   /doctors/:id/appointments/:id or /patients/:id/appointments/:id
>   doesn't feel quite right.

There is no need to complicate the endpoints to that level. If you already know the appointment id why would you reach it through the doctors or patients endpoints? It does not not matter, you reach the item directly through its collection.

```
/appointments/:appointmentid
```

> Also, what about appointments to see a particular patient or a particular doctor?

You can leverage the power of query parameters for this kind of thing. Not everything has be part of the URL template. Features like filtering of specific records could be added to the query parameters instead. For instance

```
/doctors/:doctorid/appointments?pantientName=
/patients/:patientid/appointments?doctorName=
```

> And what about appointments for each doctor or patient on a particular date?

Same thing here, you could something like:

```
/patients/:patientid/appointments?from=&to
```

Or have special endpoints for very well know cases like, my appointments for today, for this week, for this month:

```
/patients/:patientid/appointments/:year
/patients/:patientid/appointments/:year/:month
/patients/:patientid/appointments/:year/:month/:day
```

These latter could actually reuse the same logic used to implement the one getting appointments between a range of dates.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, I guess. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The URI structure is not a REST concern, because according to the uniform interface constraint it has to be decoupled from the client.

What matters:

- A specific URI (including the path and the query) can identify only a single resource.
- The URI is mapped to the resources and not to the operations, so if you use human readable nice URIs, then they will contain only nouns.

> How do I design a URL for task number 7 without having nesting like
>   /doctors/:id/patients/:id/appointments?

You can map reduce the existing appointment collection, like so:

- `/appointments?doctor=1&patient=1`
- `/appointments/doctor:1/patient:1`

> And what about appointments for each doctor or patient on a particular
>   date?

You can use a date filter to do that:

- `/appointments?date=2014-09-02`
- `/appointments/date:2014-09-02`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One question though. Wouldn't the relationship methodology require me to maintain another collection with relationships exclusively, linking to the respective documents in Doctor and Patient collections of course? This would add another atomic operation when querying the database. And I don't know how that would relate to, in terms of performance.

Comment: Nope, as I said the structure of your REST interface can be completely different from the structure of your database. Ofc if you want to store additional data about the relations, you have to change your database structure, but if not, then you can keep your current queries and database structure. REST is just a representation (or delivery method), it isn't in any connection with the database. At least not in well designed applications. I guess you should read about ports and adapters and other domain centric software architecture solutions.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to get it. I've always modeled a mostly simplistic REST API for CRUD operations. That probably explains why I'm thinking in terms of the database. Could you elaborate a little on how a route like `/doctorPatientRelationship/:relationshipId` would be handled in Express without another collection to store the relationshipId, please?

Comment: Ohh in the case you don't want persist relations, you can refer to a single relationship as `/doctorPatientRelationship/doctor:{dId}/patient:{pId}`. Or you can combine the dId with the pId into a single rId `/doctorPatientRelationship/{dId}+{pId}`

Comment: Then how does it differ from just `/doctor/:id/patient/:id`? I mean, I don't see the point of viewing it in that sense. One more question. Is having more than one parameter in a route, RESTful?

Comment: For example if you want to delete a relationship how would you do that? `DELETE /doctor/:id/patient/:id` can mean deleting the relationship and deleting the patient from the database as well... `DELETE /relations/:rid` can mean only one thing. "Is having more than one parameter in a route, RESTful?" I never heard of a rule which denies that, so yes.

Comment: Btw. describing n:m relations this way wasn't my own idea, maybe watching this can help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=5WXYw4J4QOU#t=3961 by designing your api.

Comment: Wow. Great stuff. Thank you. The DELETE point makes a lot of sense.