# Restful API naming conventions

Tags: rest, naming-conventions, restful-architecture

So me and my boss aren't agreeing here and can't find any information on it. Scenario: I want to get all the users for a certain organisation. What should the URL be?

`mydomain.com/users/by/organisation/{orgId}`

OR

`mydomain.com/organisation/{orgId}/users`

Our arguments:

Case 1: The call is expected to return "users" and therefore the "resource" (first part of the call) should relate to it.

Case 2: The organisation "owns"/"is the parent of" the user and therefore the organisation should be first.

What are your thoughts?

**UPDATE:**
I am not to worried about what comes after the `mydomain.com/{resource}`. The question relates mostly to whether the HTTP action (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) should relate to the first resource `mydomain.com/users` or whether it should reflect the relationship `mydomain.com/organisations/users/`.

Comment: can a user be a member of 2 organisations?

Comment: @SamHolder Yes, there is a linking table

Comment: Example #2 feels right to me, it seems more REST whereas the "by" feels superfluous in a URL.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778203/are-there-any-naming-convention-guidelines-for-rest-apis

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are probably aware that REST has no strict rules, you are more or less free to implement it however you like, but here are my 2 cents

```
mydomain.com/users/by/organisation/{orgId}
```

However this sounds like a good url because it sort of tells you what it does by reading it, this is not a great idea. Normally, *each url segment specifies a resource* that exists or can exist.

In this case, `users` represents one or more resources and so does `organisation`, but `by` does not, it's probably nothing more than a word to help clarify what the API does.

> The call is expected to return "users" and therefore the "resource" (first part of the call) should relate to it.

A resource is not necessarily specified in the first part of the url. It can be the 2nd, 3rd or 10th if you want

---

```
mydomain.com/organisation/{orgId}/users
```

This looks much better but I think there is 1 point of improvement. You should rename `organisation` to `organisations`, to match `users`

This

```
mydomain.com/organisations/{orgId}
```

then gets the organisation with id `orgId`, and

```
mydomain.com/organisations/{orgId}/users
```

gets all the users that belong to that organisation.

To further narrow it down you could do

```
mydomain.com/organisations/{orgId}/users/{userId}
```

to get one specific user belonging to one specific organisation

---

> **UPDATE:** I am not to worried about what comes after the
>   mydomain.com/{resource}. **The question relates mostly to whether the**
>   **HTTP action** (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) **should relate to the first**
>   **resource** mydomain.com/users or whether it should reflect the
>   relationship mydomain.com/organisations/users/.

To answer your update:

I already mentioned it above; *A resource is not necessarily specified in the first part of the url.*. If the quality of the url improves by shifting the wanted resource to the back of the url, go ahead and do so

Comment: And if it was `mydomain.com/users/organisation/{orgId}` ? I don't care much for what happens after the `/user` or `/organisations`, my question rather it whether to follow parent-child-child or relation to resuorce

Comment: @We0 i just edited this in: *A resource is not necessarily specified in the first part of the url.*. So in that case yes you want to do parent/child/child

Comment: @We0 i made a new edit to answer your update

Comment: Totally agree!!

Answer (score 6):

There is a conceptual difference between what you are trying to show here.  The first is a filtering of all the user resources in  the system based on some criteria. The second is showing the user resources that belong to an organisation.

The second url is ok for showing users that belong to an organisation I think.

The first url is effectively filtering the users that you want to see from all users.

Using the url might be ok for the filtering, though using url querystring is also be ok. so

```
mydomain.com/users?organisationId={orgId}
```

might be preferable. The urls can still contain querystrings and be restful.

Does it really make any sense to `DELETE mydomain.com/users/organisation/{orgid}`?  Would you expect that to delete the organisation? if not then this isn't really pointing at a resource and so you are doing a search, and should probably use querystrings.

There are other options for doing the search like making the search criteria a first class object, or using one of the other filtering techniques in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207477/restful-url-design-for-search)

Comment: It makes sense to me, HTTP action = delete, what am I deleting = user where organisation = id.

Comment: then would `DELETE mydomain.com/organisation/{orgId}/users` delete users or organisations that contain that user?

Answer (score 6):

Let me start with this: technically, it shouldn't really matter. REST states that URL's must be discoverable through links, like links in normal (HTML) web pages.

However, a consistent, self-explanatory URL-structure won't harm at all. I'd suggest a hierarchical structure in URLs:

- `/organisations` returns a list of all organisations
- `/organisations/123` returns a specific organisation (#123)
- `/organisations/123/users` returns a list of users that are associated to that organisation
- etc.

An alternative would be using a query string for filtering:

- `/users` returns a list of all users
- `/users?organisation=123` returns a list of users that are associated to that organisation

From this hierarchical perspective, `/users/by/organisation/123` wouldn't make much sense. What would be the result of calling `/users/by/organisation`? Or `/users/by`?

Answer (score 3):

> mydomain.com/users/by/organisation/{orgId}

What does "by" mean? That has no relationship to anything. Try to [keep random words out of the URL](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2014/05/restful-urls-actions-need-not-apply).

> Case 1: The call is expected to return "users" and therefore the "resource" (first part of the call) should relate to it.

That is not a rule that RESTful APIs enforce or expect. It is really not that common in the industry either, and I have worked with a LOOOT of APIs. Consider it to be a folder.

- /users - a list of users
- /users/1 - user with an ID of 1
- /users/1/organizations - the orgs that user belongs to
- /organizations - a list of orgs
- /organizations/1 - Organization number 1
- /organizations/1/users - The users for that organization

You are look at it like a programmer, like it is SOAP or a PHP function, trying to make `getUsersByOrganization($orgId)` and that is not how REST works. :)

IF you have to stick to case 1 (first URI segment = return type) then do this:

- /users?orgId=1

That is perfectly RESTful and it is essentially just a filter. You could even do both, but I wouldn't. It is a relationship which has no place there. I try and keep filters to things like: ?active=true

Answer (score 0):

The second is better. Walking down the URI should narrow the request, either as filters or showing parent-child objects. Users belong to an organization, so it should be organization/users. But I'd get rid of the "organization" level of the URI too if possible.

```
mydomain.com/{orgId}/users
```

Comment: I can't drop the organisations part because we have /users, /orders etc, but thanks

Comment: Let me ask it for you this way, if I wanted to delete all the users for an organisation would you recommend `DELETE /organisations/{orgId}/users`? Somehow in my head I got it that the HTTP action (PUT, POST, DELETE, GET) should relate to the resource...

Comment: Yes. The verb is what you do with the resource. You `GET` a list of all users at `/organisations/{orgId}/users` so if you want to `DELETE` all the users, you use the same address. Both addresses access the same resource(s), but the verb specifies what you do with/to that resource.

Comment: Yeah, but I am not "GETTING" or "DELETING" organisations, I am "GETTING" users?

Comment: you are getting or deleting the users that belong to the organisation

Comment: Imagine they are parent-child objects. You open the "Organization" box, and find all the "users" inside it and delete them.

Comment: And when a user can belong to more than one organization, does this still make sense?

Answer (score 0):

By REST the URI structure does matter only from human perspective. It does not matter from the perspective of the REST client, because it is following link annotated with semantics.

To answer your question, it matter what do you want to describe, relationships or users. If you want to add and remove relationships, then you have to define a relationship collection. If you want to add and remove users, then you have to define an user collection. This matters only by manipulation. By GET you can define any kind of query which returns a bunch of users...

Comment: Sorry if duplicate, but couldn't find anything on it...

Comment: Similar questions from the last 2 days: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957974/writing-a-rest-api-for-complex-nested-data
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011490/rest-array-manipulation-best-practice
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001825/what-is-the-correct-rest-endpoint-for-adding-an-item-to-an-array-field

Comment: May I inquire as to the many edits you've done which totally overhaul the answers?

Comment: I correct my old answers about REST. I wrote them before reading scientific articles in the topic, so most of them are totally wrong.

Comment: Btw. I got about 70 to go (every day 10 is allowed afaik). Should I stop this?

Comment: It's a bit much, yes. Maybe ones like this where there are other answers and you have no votes either way on yours, you could delete instead. And don't do quite so many at a time. Also, don't forget to @-reply so I get notified

Comment: @AndrewBarber Ok, I'll delete where I can, but I have 5 deletes/day limit, so that won't be fast either...

Comment: @inf3rno Not a problem at all. :-)